# Group BY query utilizes indexes, but window function query doesn't

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, maximo, oracle19c

I use a COTS system by IBM called *Maximo Asset Management*. The system has a WORKORDER table with 350,000 rows.

Maximo has a concept called [*relationships*](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mam/7.6.1.2?topic=applications-creating-relationships-between-parent-child-tables) that can be used to pull in data from related records.

How relationships work:

**For each individual** WORKORDER record, the system uses the WHERE clause from the relationship to run a select query to pull in the related record ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaFOg.png)).

---

**Related Records:**

In this case, the related records are rows in a custom database view called WO**TASK**ROLLUP_VW.

In a related post, I explored different SQL rollup techniques that I could use in the view: [Group by x, get other fields too](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299932/group-by-x-get-other-fields-too-comparing-options-and-performance).  The options I explored performed similarly to each other when I ran them on the full WORKORDER table.

However, in reality, Maximo is designed to only get one row at a time -- via individual select statements. As such, the queries are **performing very differently** when only selecting a single WORKORDER record.

---

*I’ve wrapped each query in an outer query with a WHERE clause that selects a specific work order. I’ve done this to mimic what Maximo does when it uses relationships.*

**Query 1b:** (GROUP BY; selective aggregates)

Performance is **very good**, even when only selecting a single record, because indexes were used (only 37 milliseconds).

```
select
    *
from
    (
    select 
        wogroup as wonum, 
        sum(actlabcost)  as actlabcost_tasks_incl,
        sum(actmatcost)  as actmatcost_tasks_incl,
        sum(acttoolcost) as acttoolcost_tasks_incl,
        sum(actservcost) as actservcost_tasks_incl,
        sum(actlabcost + actmatcost + acttoolcost + actservcost) as acttotalcost_tasks_incl,
        max(case when istask = 0 then rowstamp end) as other_wo_columns
    from 
        maximo.workorder
    group by 
        wogroup
    )
where
    wonum in ('WO360996')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                 |     1 |    34 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY NOSORT        |                 |     1 |    34 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| WORKORDER       |     1 |    34 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | WORKORDER_NDX32 |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   3 - access("WOGROUP"='WO360996')
```

---

**Query #2:** (SUM window function)

Performance is relatively **slow**, when selecting a single record, because indexes weren't used (3 seconds).

```
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        wonum,
        actlabcost_tasks_incl,
        actmatcost_tasks_incl,
        acttoolcost_tasks_incl,
        actservcost_tasks_incl,
        acttotalcost_tasks_incl,
        other_wo_columns
    from
        (
        select
            wonum,
            istask,
            sum(actlabcost ) over (partition by wogroup) as actlabcost_tasks_incl,
            sum(actmatcost ) over (partition by wogroup) as actmatcost_tasks_incl,
            sum(acttoolcost) over (partition by wogroup) as acttoolcost_tasks_incl,
            sum(actservcost) over (partition by wogroup) as actservcost_tasks_incl,
            sum(actlabcost + actmatcost + acttoolcost + actservcost) over (partition by wogroup) as acttotalcost_tasks_incl,
            rowstamp as other_wo_columns
        from
            maximo.workorder
        )
    where
        istask = 0
    )
where
    wonum in ('WO360996')
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |           |   355K|    61M|       | 14789   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW               |           |   355K|    61M|       | 14789   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   WINDOW SORT       |           |   355K|    14M|    21M| 14789   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| WORKORDER |   355K|    14M|       | 10863   (2)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("WONUM"='WO360996' AND "ISTASK"=0)
```

---

**Question:**

Why was the GROUP BY query in #1B able to use indexes (fast), but the Sum Window Function in #2 wasn't able to use indexes (slow)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two queries are different as the first on you use:

```sql
select wogroup as wonum,
```

And the second one you just use:

```sql
select wonum,
```

Which means you won't use an index on `WOGROUP` as you are filtering on the `WONUM` column instead of the `WOGROUP` column (that just happens to have been aliased to `WONUM`).

It looks like your second query could be corrected and reduced (by moving the filter to the inner sub-query and get rid of the partition by as you are then already filtering) to:

```sql
select wonum,
       actlabcost_tasks_incl,
       actmatcost_tasks_incl,
       acttoolcost_tasks_incl,
       actservcost_tasks_incl,
       acttotalcost_tasks_incl,
       other_wo_columns
from   (
  select wogroup AS wonum,
         istask,
         sum(actlabcost ) over () as actlabcost_tasks_incl,
         sum(actmatcost ) over () as actmatcost_tasks_incl,
         sum(acttoolcost) over () as acttoolcost_tasks_incl,
         sum(actservcost) over () as actservcost_tasks_incl,
         sum(actlabcost + actmatcost + acttoolcost + actservcost) over () as acttotalcost_tasks_incl,
         rowstamp as other_wo_columns
  from   maximo.workorder
  where  wogroup = 'WO360996'
)
where istask = 0;
```